# Plone, extend portalmembership.getMemberInfo method

Tags: plone

I made an extended user schema in my Plone 4.3 site with the collective.example.userdata.
My problem is when I try to display my new fields in author.cpt page.
I used to get my user object with the getMemberById from membershiptool and then use getProperty on the userobject but it requires a "manager" permission.

Maybe a solution would be to extend the getMemberInfo with my new fields but I don't know how to do such a thing. 
Anyone ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem and ended up monkey patching `Products.PlonePAS.tools.membership.MembershipTool.getMemberInfo` so it supply more data to the caller. The method `getMemberInfo` can be called with/from the Anonymous role.